# Illustrator pdf-export options not available

Tags: adobe-illustrator

since updating my OS to Catalina a quite important option within Illustrator CC2015 is greyed out. I can't "convert colors (keep numbers)" as it is constantly greyed out, no matter the document.
I suppose that has something to do with missing elements within my library or settings. But which

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Only CC2019 & 2020 work properly with Catalina. Older versions rely on 32-bit libraries which Catalina will not use. As you have a subscription-based Adobe account, why don't you update? 2020 is a whole lot better than 5 years earlier. [I wouldn't jump to 2021 for a month or three, just to be safe.]

Comment: @Tetsujin I do have both apps. But 2020 is running (basically it's not the working speed nor the running speed, but opening up the app is just ridiculoulsly slow) so damn slow that I need to prevent it in quite a lot of times if I e.g. work on recurring tasks that are tracked by the hour

Comment: You have my sympathies - but the 32-bit libs are gone forever with Catalina & beyond. There is simply no fix, as Catalina has no 32-bit support at all. I'm afraid I can't test any of this, as a) I'm still on Mojave & b) I haven't seen CC2015 since… 2015 ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what version CC2015 is but maybe too old to work with OS Catalina ?

[image]

Comment: Illustrator 20.1 - but isn't it weird that anythign works corretcly but that particular option including the fact that I can't choose pdf/x3 or x/4 is available? Couldn't that be solved by updating presets/settings...?

Comment: I have been avoiding Catalina- Happy with Mojave so far. I am worried about how many of my programs won't work properly...

Comment: .... and here I am sticking to Yosemite for that very reason... :)

Comment: btw, 23.1 is CC2019, 24 is CC 2020.